# Disaster relief donations as a rotating ad?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I've added a link to an organization ([Compassion International](http://www.compassion.com)) doing disaster relief in Haiti to my [blog](http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com).  While I'm not sure that it would be appropriate to regularly run ads for charities, I wonder if, in the event of a disaster, it would be acceptable to run ads for organizations like the Red Cross/Red Crescent and other disaster relief organizations as part of the rotating ads.  I'm sure most of us aren't waiting until we see an SO ad to make a donation, but it seems in keeping with @Jeff's spirit of giving back to the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree that running ads for charity reguarly might not be a good fit... but, we'll join the effort.
[ad http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/supportHaitiRelief.png](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/supportHaitiRelief.png)

Answer (score 5):

I'd be all for it.  But of course I'm not getting any ad revenue in from the site...  If not an ad, maybe a little block directly above or below the ad.

Comment: I believe that they are already running free ads for OSS projects.  This would, I think, simply fit in that rotation unless they wanted to put it on every page view.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

The idea itself is quite good, but Charity is a minefield though - way too many scammers in that field, including once reputable ones like [UNICEF](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/article/0,,3111092,00.html). Running an ad for a scamming Charity is like running an ad for Scientology.

The American Red Cross is also not without it's controversies, but I think them and Médecins Sans Frontières (Doctors without Borders) should be okay. What I'm saying really is: The team should REALLY make sure only to advertise Charities that are proven good, as it could backfire quite a bit.

Also of note are religious-led charities. I wouldn't be offended personally, but religion is always a minefield.

Comment: I completely agree on both points. I personally would not donate my money to a religious-led charity, but there's no harm in providing a link to one or many charities.

Answer (score 0):

I think if someone wants to donate they will do it with or without the ad.. It's not something like "Product X" that maybe is not known to the person viewing the page; I believe all of us are familiar with what happened and know that donations are appreciated.