# Redesign community wiki edited posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, community-wiki, user-card

Currently when community wiki posts are edited, the user icon is only shown for the last editor and not for the person who owns most of the content.

At a glance, I usually tend to mistake the last editor for the main author due to the icon presence. This is not desirable because it dilutes authorship.

[image: current wiki]

I suggest just removing the author of the last edit and just leave it like

[image: suggested wiki]

That way the only shown author is the main author of the content. If you care about who has edited you can review the edit history.

Answer (score 6):

This was particularly a problem on the recent Moderator nominations, with answers like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35583/nominations-new-stack-overflow-moderator/35665#35665), where Peter Mortensen edited grammar/spelling on a bunch of posts, which made it look at first glance like he was nominating himself repeatedly.

[image]

Working out who was nominating themselves became a bit more difficult (though admittedly most users put their name or a link to their profile in their nomination, and those posts only have one edit, so the post still reads - currently, at least - "Shoban 88%" at the bottom).

Comment: I still don't understand *why* this was a problem; given that there were a far number of 3rd-party nominations, no one should have been looking at the author / last editor for nominee names *anyway*...

Answer (score 3):

I rather agree with that, for the reasons given, too often I mistake the last editing person for the author.

I would add that such change would push community wiki posts further in their role, it would become further less about the persons, and simply about the actual message.

Answer (score 3):

This is in, but it has a side-effect.

Since the community wiki calculation does not display percentages when *all the edits are by the same person*, posts of that type will look ownerless.

You'll see.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about this. Wasn't there some other way of doing this?

Comment: Hey man, I just implement the requests. I can't help it if the requests don't make any sense.

Comment: Since their "community" posts by definition, with loose ties to the author, is that really such a bad thing?

Comment: can't you just make it say "username 100%"?

Comment: So right now, the username and avatar are shown, but only until the user edits the answer. Then it becomes anonymous until another person edits it. I dunno about this...

Comment: Here's an example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36209/disaster-relief-donations-as-a-rotating-ad - notice that you cannot tell who originated it, and there are no edits at all.

Comment: @Kip: You should create that as a new suggestion

Comment: @Pollyanna: Since they are "community" posts, does it really matter that we know who originated the question?

Comment: @anonjr - I'd argue that if any one person has made more than 50% of the current text, then there is some value in knowing that this person made the majority of the post, even though it's community wiki.  In most cases, this is the originator of the post.  But if the original poster now owns less than 50% of it, then no, there's no significant value in knowing this.

Comment: @Jeff: They currently don't look ownerless to me. If they did some days ago it seems you actually thought out a bit and saw the easy and sane way out for a change. Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

> This is not desirable because it dilutes authorship.

I don't really have a problem with that for CW posts, but agree that it can lead to confusion and, sad to say, hurt feelings in some cases. So I'd be fine with this change.

However, I suspect if this was implemented, the number of complaints regarding the behavior of the [attribution percentage calculations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35972/diff-percentage-seems-a-bit-off) might increase...

Answer (score 1):

What about hiding the icon for the last editor, and instead showing it for the original answerer?

Comment: What about showing none? CW posts are in a sense *ownerless*.

Comment: Then why show anyone's name at all?

Answer (score 0):

If one person contributed more than 51% of the content, show that person's avatar, and none other.

Otherwise, show no avatars.