# Community Wiki and Attribution of Authorship

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

This changed yesterday, in response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36286/).

I'm not sure what others feel - I'd like it if there was a gravatar image shown reflecting the user who's contributed the most. At present there's no hint who wrote the below answer.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read [Jeff's answer in the question you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36286/):

> This is in, but it has a side-effect.
>
> Since the community wiki calculation
>   does not display percentages when all
>   the edits are by the same person,
>   posts of that type will look
>   ownerless.
>
> You'll see.

And its comments, in particular this very good question:

> can't you just make it say "username
>   100%"? – Kip 19 hours ago