# Revision history & community wiki links show the same page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, community-wiki

On community wiki posts both the revision history link & community wiki links lead to the same page.

Shouldn't the username in the community wiki post point to the user profile page?

**Revision link**
[hard to see screenshot of revision link hover http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/5537/62141873.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/5537/62141873.png)

**Community wiki link**
[even harder to see screenshot of explained linkage http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/4535/27703557.png](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/4535/27703557.png)

Comment: Candidly, if I'd found this post, it's similar enough to what's [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179719/user-names-on-community-wiki-posts-should-link-to-profile-pages-like-they-do-ev?noredirect=1#comment548676_179719) that I probably would have edited this, rather than posting a new one.  In any case, I'm marking this complete.

Answer (score 3):

This was always the way. It wasn't until recently that the [last editor link was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36286/redesign-community-wiki-edited-posts).

Community wiki posts are less about individual users and more about the collective work of all.

On non-CW posts, the last edited time links to the revision list. On the area noting the author (bottom right), it would link to the author.

Since a CW post is a group effort (ideals, man, they're glossy), it displays the author who contributed most overall (on a rough percentage) to the latest version of the post. It also links to the revision list to show you all of the authors/contributors to that post.

Again, on CW, it's about the Borg and not about the red shirt.

Comment: i got your point random, since the username under the communitywiki shows the owner of the post and the edited or answered link already point to the revision history , we can link the username to his profile page.

Comment: Edited link will only be shown wheen there is a collaborative edit. no meaning here to have same links twice....