# When community wiki post has only one revision, text is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki

I just stumbled over [this CW answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137161/152859):

> [image]

It should be just "answered [time stamp]" but looks like the "edited" was hard coded somehow.

I verified this to  happen on all CW posts without edits i.e. only one revision exists.

Guess it started after [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179719/152859) was implemented - you win some, you lose some. :)

Edit: now I noticed the "edited" was removed, but "answered" is not part of the link which just makes it inconsistent:

> [image]

Comment: Per your edits, the "edited" text no longer appears in this case; if your remaining request is to make the text "answered" part of the link as well, you may want to edit the title and body of your post to focus specifically on that.

Comment: @V2Blast no, all good, this appears to have been fixed at some point. You can throw a completed tag on it. Thanks!