# On question pages, the entire phrase, "Edited on MM/DD/ at TT" now links to the edit history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, revisions-list

Previously,  only the date/time part was a link, which was highly undiscoverable:

> [image]

Now, it **all** does:

> [image]

**Are you as happy as I am?**

Comment: "And your question is?"...

Comment: Did you fix the "Answered Edited" thing? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181289/when-community-wiki-post-has-only-one-revision-text-is-incorrect

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't think so, but there are some CW tweaks in the works that may address it.

Comment: @matt, my question is, "Are you as happy as I am that 'On question pages, the entire phrase, “Edited on MM/DD/ at TT” now links to the edit history'"? ;)

Comment: @Jaydles: Will you accept an answer of "Yes"?

Comment: Usually you would post the request then the dev who did the hard work will post the answer, like you guys did [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179719/152859). But hey, it's all good as it is. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: yes, yes we are!]