# Should we update the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, faq-update-request

With the addition of the new feature request completed here: [On question pages, the entire phrase, "Edited on MM/DD/ at TT" now links to the edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181361/on-question-pages-the-entire-phrase-edited-on-mm-dd-at-tt-now-links-to-the), should we update the FAQ pages?

[image]

Comment: I guess we could update it but this is not the only thing that would need to change.

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk that's a good point. This was just an observation that I thought could/should be pointed out.