# On the active questions list, the entire phrase "modified XX ago" should be a link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Recently, [the whole "edited on XX/YY" phrase was made to link to the edit history of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181361/on-question-pages-the-entire-phrase-edited-on-mm-dd-at-tt-now-links-to-the).

> [image: yay, it's a link!]

But with the similar "modified XX ago" text on the active questions list, still only the time/date part is a link.

> [image: no link makes me sad]

Can the whole "modified XX ago" phrase be a link as well?

Comment: Consistency. Yep. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ... or conspiracy? Even though there's freehand red and blue circles, this feature still isn't implemented, surely something is going on...

Comment: @Laf "Talking to the devs" means 6-8 weeks. And this means... 6-8 weeks. We just have to be patient, put bounty from time to time and hope for the best. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I prefer the conspiracy theory, much funnier ;)

Comment: By the way, homepage have the whole "asked/modified/answered X time ago" linked. Thats inconsistent with "active" tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implemented in build rev `2014.11.28.2805` on meta and `2014.11.28.2052` on the sites.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, I overlooked this.  Talking to the devs, and will make consistent assuming no unforeseen complexities.

Comment: I am commenting here instead of posting a duplicate question. There are really only a few reasons that a post ends up in the list. It was either edited or it was answered (or bountied which is already evident). It would be nice if a) the whole phrase was a link to the new content, and b) that the word modified be replaced with answered if the new content is in the form of an answer.

Comment: I am commenting here instead of posting a triplicate question... There's also a bounty now!

Comment: Hmm. Thought we fixed this.  Having someone figure out if it fell through the cracks or if there was some complexity.  (Yes, I know I lack credibility on "I'll look into this one" at the moment.)

Comment: Okay, confirmed that we dropped this ball somewhere, but it's back in business.  Stay tuned.