# Clicking User's Name Leads Me to Editing History of Question

Tags: bug, community-wiki

When clicking the OP's name in this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats), it sends me to the editing history of the question.

Normally, clicking on the OP's name will redirect me to the OP's profile. So when I click on `Kevin`, I expect to be redirected to Kevin's profile. So why does clicking the OP's username redirect me to the editing history of the question instead of the OP's profile?

Comment: Bug, it [should indeed link to profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179719/user-names-on-community-wiki-posts-should-link-to-profile-pages-like-they-do-ev)

Comment: I [pinged Kevin Montrose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179719/user-names-on-community-wiki-posts-should-link-to-profile-pages-like-they-do-ev#comment763789_180729) back in the days, pointing out [this bug report on Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13785/147263)... 'twas in May 2014.

Comment: @pizza I pinged again.

Comment: Here is link to another similar post: [User names on community wiki posts link to revision histories if they're never edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303967)