# User names on community wiki posts link to revision histories if they're never edited

Tags: bug, community-wiki, revisions-list

Related:

- [User names on community wiki posts should link to profile pages (like they do everywhere else)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179719/350567)
- [Revision history & community wiki links show the same page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37921/350567)

This is even stranger because this bug occurs **only when there's no revision**, i.e. never edited after it was originally posted (and the grace period had gone). You can easily find a lot of unedited CWs in the sandbox or the sandbox archive. For example [this one](/a/303612/350567).

Comment: Well, the bug is also in the full site theme, not related to mobile web. With no edits, it indeed still links to the revisions list.

Comment: Is it possible that the bug happens for posts which have been made CW and they have no edits after they were converted to CW? See also some related comments here: [Clicking question author username sends to revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4607) and [Clicking on the username goes to revision history for CW](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/clicking-on-the-username-goes-to-revision-history-for-cw)

Comment: The same problem was recently pointed out on MathOverflow Meta: [Clicking question author username sends to revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4607). Here is an older bug report on Mathematics Meta: [User name incorrectly linked to revision history](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13785).